# Why is the IFS value removed from the file while splitting?

Tags: shell-script, command-substitution, bash-expansion

```
IFS=$'?\n'
for line in $(cat "./newfiletoread")
do printf "${line}\n"
done
```

The file contents are as below:
Hello there!How are you doing?How is life?Mine is as boring as a winter morning!

The code above splits the contents of the file when it comes across a '?' or '!' or '/n' which is nice. But, during the expansion the shell removes these characters from the file. The below is the output that I get.

```
Hello there 
How are you doing
How is life
Mine is as boring as a winter morning
```

I understand that it is how shell works by substituting these IFS values with spaces before the command executes. Is there a way to preserve these delimiter characters during the splitting? I would like to get my output like this one below:

```
Hello there! 
How are you doing?
How is life?
Mine is as boring as a winter morning!
```

Comment: what does the original file look like?

Comment: All four lines as one. No space or new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [don't read the lines of a file with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

I read this somewhere about splitting strings: use `split` when you know what to throw away; use a regular expression when you know what you want to keep. Or something like that.

The problem with using shell word splitting using `$IFS` is that any char in that variable is used to split, and you can't know which one.

With bash, you can write:

```
line='Hello there! How are you doing? How is life? Mine is as boring as a winter morning!'
line=${line//\?/$'"?\n'}
line=${line//\!/$'"!\n'}
echo "$line"
```

```
Hello there"!
 How are you doing"?
 How is life"?
 Mine is as boring as a winter morning"!
```

Note the leading spaces. That can be worked around with a more complicated pattern: `line=${line//\?*([[:blank:]])/$'"?\n'}`

I would use `sed` instead:

```
line='Hello there! How are you doing? How is life? Mine is as boring as a winter morning!'
new=$( sed 's/[?!][[:blank:]]*/&\n/g' <<<"$line" )
echo "$new"
```

```
Hello there! 
How are you doing? 
How is life? 
Mine is as boring as a winter morning!
```

---

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) has a `split()` function that does let you capture the separators, but using it is pretty verbose:

```
echo "$line" | awk '{
    n = split($0, words, /[!?][[:blank:]]*/, seps)
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
        print words[i] seps[i]
    print words[n]}
'
```

Comment: Ok. Sed seems to be perfect. Thanks! But how do you read a file line by line without a loop?

Comment: The answer is in the link I provided